# generating gulp-angular documentation with generator-ngdoc

Tags: angularjs, gulp, documentation, ngdoc

I am having a hard time generating documentation for my [gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular)  based project: I am using this generator to generate a docs folder inside of my project: [generator-ngdoc](https://github.com/Quramy/generator-ngdoc) (dgeni based). Whenever I open the documentation for a component I am getting this error.

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'appModule' is 
not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load 
it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies 
as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/nomod?p0=appModule
  at angular.js:68
  at angular.js:2127
  at ensure (angular.js:2051)
  at Object.module (angular.js:2125)
  at modules.js:5
  at modules.js:20
```

in `modules.js`  there is the following code:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('appModule')
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$logProvider', 'ngToastProvider'];

  function config($logProvider, ngToastProvider) {
    // Enable log
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
    ngToastProvider.configure({
      animation: 'slide',// or 'fade'
      verticalPosition: 'bottom',
      horizontalPosition: 'left'
    });
  }

})();

/* global moment:false */
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('appModule')
    .constant('moment', moment);

})();

/**
 *
 * @ngdoc module
 * @name appModule
 * @module appModule
 * @packageName agirc-arrco
 * @description
 * This is a sample module.
 *
 **/
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('appModule', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 
'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngAria', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 
'ui.bootstrap', 'agr.components.stepper', 'agr.components.toggle',
  'agr.components.accordionrow', 'angularMoment', 
'agr.components.header', 'agr.filters.period', 'agr.directives.limit- 
 to', 'env.config']);

  })();
```

I am not sure but is seems that dgeni is including the module config before the module declaration itself. any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : The modules files should be added separately to `gulp/module.js` in the `gulp.src` task